# IIFE, javascript, function undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my IIFE function

```
var test = function(){
  console.log('fire');
}();
```

It invokes at start. But how do I call this again?

```
var fireTestFn = function(){
   test();
}

fireTestFn(); // test() is not a function
```

JSbin https://jsbin.com/cesuzimogu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return `test` from inside using a named function expression.

```
var test = function fn(){
  console.log('fire');
  return fn;
}();
```

Comment: Then why not remove `()` and assign normal `function`  to `test`

Comment: I agree, but it can make sense to wish to have a run on declaration. What you point out is kinda related to the reasons behind the question, rather than my answer to it. But as I said, I gotta to agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

*The result* of the IIFE will be assigned to `test`, which is obviously *not a function*, because you're not returning a function from the IFEE (or anything for that matter). Keep it simple; what you want is a named function you can call anytime as many times as you want:

```
function test() {
    console.log('fire');
}
test();  // call as often as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says

> test() is not a function

When you self-invoked the function, the **result** was stored into `test`.

In order to be able to use `test` as a function and call repeatedly elsewhere, do not self-invoke

```
var test = function(){
  console.log('fire');
};
```

or have the function return an inner function

```
var test = function () {
    return function () {
        console.log('fire');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
var myNamespace = {};

(function(ns) {
    ns.test = function(){
      console.log('fire');
    };

    /*ns.myOtherFunction = function(var1) { }*/
})(myNamespace);

var fireTestFn = function(){
   myNamespace.test();
};

fireTestFn();
```

See example here: https://jsbin.com/helumoveqe/edit?js,console